# Port is open and apache is listening but on browser "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT" error

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7, firewalld

i have centos 7 and installed apache server on vps. listening 80, 8002 ports in `httpd.conf`

```
Listen 80
Listen 8002
```

also checked the `$ netstat -anp | grep 8002`

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8002            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10186/httpd
```

there is no problem. it's listening and I opened the port via firewalld and --reload

here is the opened ports  `$ firewall-cmd --list-ports`, output

```
80/tcp 8002/tcp
```

the result is, when I check the  on the browser. I can see website on port `80` BUT on `<IP address:8002>` there is problem. It tries to connect and in the end `"ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT"` error is returning.

So I went to terminal and the address with a `$ telnet <IP address> 8002` and it returned `connected`

Additionally I run `curl <IP address:8002>` and it returned the `html` without a problem as expected. But I am not very sure why I can't connect the `:8002` on browser. And why I can see the `:80`... what is the difference?

virtual-host conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/dom1/
    ErrorLog /var/www/dom1/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/dom1/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8002>
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/dom2/
    ErrorLog /var/www/dom2/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/dom2/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for the virtual hosting configurations. Running sites on different ports.

Reference Link:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#virtualhost
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.htm.

I would recommend you to check for the apache error logs and use the correct server name.

Listen 80
Listen 8080

ServerName www.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/www/domain-80"

ServerName www.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/www/domain-8080"

ServerName www.example.org
    DocumentRoot "/www/otherdomain-80"

ServerName www.example.org
    DocumentRoot "/www/otherdomain-8080"

Comment: I updated  question with the virtual-host file, could you please check it and tell me do you see anything wrong?

Comment: i checked updated answer of yours but nothing changed... still same problem